# Scrapy scraping from webpages

Tags: python, scrapy

While creating a spider with Scrapy, I encountered something I don't seem to get over.

```
for quote in response.css('div.entry-content'):
        yield {
             'title': quote.css('h3.widget-title::text').extract_first(),
             'text': quote.css('div p::text').extract_first(),
```

This is the thing that I want to extract, so getting the `p` and `title` from the `div.panel-layout`, but once the `p` reaches a `strong` or anything inside said `p`, the scraping ends for that page.

Giving an (text) example would be

```
The class **LocalTime**
```

after which, the spider ends the activity after encountering **LocalTime** as a `strong`.

I have tried adding `p::text strong::text` but doesn't seem to get around it. How would I go around said problem, advice and hints are more than appreciated.

Edit1: I have solved the problem partially by removing `::text` from `p::text` but now it gives me the code for everything inside it as follows `<p> The class <strong>LocalTime</strong> ... </p>`

Comment: Can you please provide an URL for the page you are trying  to scrape and the data you want to extract from it?

Comment: [Here you go](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/10/java-localtime/), it is just a test for scraping, in no way did I think of it as anything else.

Comment: Could you post webpage you are scraping or whole html bit you are struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this (XPath `string()` function):

```
for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="entry-content"]'):
        yield {
             'title': quote.xpath('./h3[@class="widget-title"]/text()').extract_first(),
             'text': quote.xpath('string(./div/p)').extract_first(),
}
```

Comment: I have found the solution using the xpath, as you said and it looks like `'text': quote.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/article[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/p/text()').extract(),`. Otherwise it doesn't show the text in a nice format. While the title is `'titleInArticle': quote.xpath('//header/h1/text()').extract(),` and displays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understand you correctly. 
You wish to scrape the 'p' tag without the 'strong' tag? 
If so, it is not possible - you should use regex to remove it.
Like this:

```
   re.findall(r'>(.+?)<', "<p> The class <strong>LocalTime</strong> ... </p>")
```

Comment: I wish to include it, because in my in question it doesn't appear, it ends as it reaches the `strong`.

Comment: So if you managed to scrape the "<p> The class <strong>LocalTime</strong> ... </p>", which basing on the EDIT1 in your question I can tell you did, then with help of regex you can get rid of the tags.

Comment: While it did remove the tags from the result, it didn't remove the tags from all urls (i scrape 3 at once, for this example).

Comment: I do not understand, could you provide me with an example?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the regex didn't remove the characters, some I thought were `strong` weren't in fact normal text. Maybe I put the regex wrong.